# Is it possible to use key:value in typeahead for bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I use this [typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) plugin for bootstrap 3. Is it possible to do search by keys and insert values when key selected? For example i have data like `{'GKA': 'Goroka', 'Madang': 'MAG', 'HGU': 'Mount Hagen' }`, when i enter `G` it shoudl show me `Goroka`

Comment: take a look at this one 

[here is the link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136973/bootstrap-typeahead-return-name-and-id

Answer (score 0):

in your case

json array

```
var jsonData=
[
{

'id':'GKA'
'name':'Goroka', 

'id':MAG'
'name':'Madang', 

 }
 ];


var Names = new Array();
var Ids = new Object();
```

//where ever u want u call this function,may be page on load

```
 function ( jsonData )
        {
            $.each( jsonData, function ( index, item )
            {
                Names.push( item.name );
                Ids[item.name] = item.id;
            } );
            $( '#product' ).typeahead( { source:Names } );
```

get the name

```
 $( '#product' ).val()
```

and get the id

```
productIds[$( '#product' ).val()]
```